# Using df.iloc[ ].copy to get specific columns, naming columns I see error: Expected axis has x elements new values have x elements

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I have the below code, my df.iloc is getting the 4 columns I need the other columns I don't need, however when I do df.columns I see the error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 19 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t', skiprows=1, header=None,
                 storage_options={'key': s3_access[0],
                                  'secret': s3_access[1]})

# checking if file has 19 columns.
if df.shape[1] == 19:
    df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[2:5, 6]].copy()
    df.columns = ['normalized_page_url', 'impression_id', 'ts', 'user_ip_country']
```

This is what df prints before df.columns, sorry I'm printing the log in airflow and it cuts off some of the columns, but if you see on the bottom it does say there are 4 columns:

```
0       vi/comunita-asmr-porno...  ...  it
1       vicvvivere-c...  ...  it
2        viowbar  ...  it
3         viirting  ...  it
4       viria-du...  ...  it
...                                                   ...  ...  ..
528180  vilice-tas...  ...  us
528181  vic-use...  ...  us
528182  vis...  ...  us
528183  vss-story-...  ...  us
528184  v-being-...  ...  us

[528185 rows x 4 columns]
[2022-01-12 00:47:23,504]
```

and this is what happens when I print out `df.columns` before setting the columns with `df.columns = ...`

```
Int64Index([2, 3, 4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Do you mind printing the value of `df.columns` after the `df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[2:5, 6]].copy()` line but before the `df.columns = ...` line?

Comment: @NickODell I'm running in airflow, and the logs cut off some values because there are thousands of rows but I've added  it just now to the question :) thanks for taking a look!